# WPF MVVM: How to avoid creating multiple instances of a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing a multi-page WPF app using MVVM and I'm having a problem I can't seem to solve effectively.
If there's an error at any point in the app, I've created single sub-view that can be shown inside a view to display the error and info on any page (View).

The way I'm trying to do this is:

1. The page (View) has a ViewModel that handles the business logic including determining something went wrong. It will then create an instance of the Error Sub-View inside a content control where the error will be displayed.
2. The ViewModel signals which error has occurred by calling a public method on the Sub-View's ViewModel and passes this function a byte index so the Error Sub-View can lookup and get the information to be displayed.
3. The Sub-ViewModel sets this error info in a property "ActiveError". ActiveError has a RaisePropertyChanged method and the Error Sub-View has text fields bound to this property to display the data.

Simple stuff. However, the Error Sub-View is displayed but never with any data.

I thought I solved this by making ActiveError static until I figured out what was really happening (I think). The ActiveError data isn't being shown because in this process, 3 instances of the Error Sub-ViewModel are being created.

One is created when we create the Sub-ViewModel:

#### Page ViewModel

New Sub-ViewModel instance

```
ConnectionErrorVM = new ConnectionErrorViewModel();
CurrentView = ConnectionErrorVM;
```

#### Page Xaml

New Sub-View instance

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="ConnectionErrorViewTemplate" 
               DataType="{x:Type vm:ConnectionErrorViewModel}">
      <v:ConnectionErrorView DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources> ...

//Further down the page in grid
<ContentControl x:Name="ConnectionMessagesView" 
               Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
```

And now the second is created here:

#### Sub-View Xaml

Second Sub-ViewModel

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:SystemErrors/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And now the 3rd:

#### Page ViewModel###

Calling the SetActiveError method

```
SystemErrors error = new SystemErrors();
error.SetActiveError(errorCodeToIndex);
```

It seems like this is a useful approach for a lot of things in MVVM, but I can't think of a way to do it without this without the extra instances because the datacontext must always be set in the Sub-View and the PageView model will always have to create an instance to call a method. How do approach this without band-aids like singletons or being fine with doing things wrong because the static keyword saves us?

Comment: UserControls - or controls in general - should never have their own private view models. And hence never explicitly assign such a private view model object to their DataContext property. They should instead operate on a view model object in the DataContext that they inherit from their parent element.

Comment: And whenever you write `DataContext="{Binding}"` this makes no sense at all. It assigns the current value of the DataContext property to the DataContext property.

Comment: @Clemens: Thank you for the response! I see. My goal is to have single class that simply does error displaying. If we then make the DataContext that of the parent, then doesn't every page now need to have a bunch of repeated code to display errors? And without globals in wpf, how can a single error UserControl be bound to elements on multiple pages? Those two issues are why I tried this way.

Comment: @Clemens: Just wanted to say thank you! I did what you said above and everything worked. The only thing I had to do extra was `{Binding DataContext.ActiveError.ErrorDescription, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}`, but I think that was implied above. Thank you!!